# Amazon Redshift VACUUM was not successful

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, vacuum

My table had 17500000 rows,

I deleted  500k rows. After deleting, I ran the vacuum command.

According to [SVV_VACUUM_SUMMARY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_VACUUM_SUMMARY.html), row_delta is difference in the total number of table rows before and after the vacuum.

But when I saw the SVV_VACUUM_SUMMARY table, row_delta is 0. Shouldn't it be 500K?

Also here's the output from [STL_VACUUM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_VACUUM.html) table:

> status        rows                 sortedrows
>
> Started      17500000         813055
>
> Finished    17500000         17500000

Does this mean Vacuum wasn't successful as the rows for finished is same as when it was started?

Also [SVV_VACUUM_PROGRESS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_VACUUM_PROGRESS.html) has status as complete for the table. So want to confirm if it was successful or not.

And checked [SVV_TABLE_INFO](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html) for my table and tbl_rows has 17500000. I don't know what should be done as I think tbl_rows should be 17000000 as the vacuum operation was successful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try setting threshold ? `VACUUM DELETE ONLY TO 100 PERCENT`

Comment: have you ran `ANALYZE` after `VACUUM`?

Comment: @Ravi I did vacuum table_name to 100 percent

Comment: @AlexYes I haven't. Should I?

Comment: @ChiragSejpal try doing that, it might be that svv_table_info relies on outdated table statistics. Please let me know if that worked

Comment: @AlexYes Running vacuum table_name to 100 percent again seemed to have work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the view [`svv_table_info`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html) to confirm whether the table is correctly vacuumed.

If, for some reason, running `VACUUM my_table TO 100 PERCENT` does not result in a change in the `unsorted` value in `svv_table_info` you will need to [perform a deep copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/performing-a-deep-copy.html).

Comment: I did check svv_table_info after running vacuum as posted in my question. But didn't work. However, running vacuum table_name to 100 percent; again seemed to have work and it changed the unsorted to 0 and the row_delta in svv_vacuum_summary is now -500K.